# What should be workaound to pass MediaStream produced from MediaDevices.getUserMedia() as source to OBS Studio, VLC, youtube live, facebook live etc?

Tags: electron, blob, rtmp, mediastream, web-mediarecorder

I have a electron app which is capturing winodw and producing [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) from [`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

```
// In the renderer process.
const { desktopCapturer } = require('electron')

desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['window', 'screen'] }).then(async sources => {
  for (const source of sources) {
    if (source.name === 'Electron') {
      try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: false,
          video: {
            mandatory: {
              chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
              chromeMediaSourceId: source.id,
              minWidth: 1280,
              maxWidth: 1280,
              minHeight: 720,
              maxHeight: 720
            }
          }
        })
        handleStream(stream)
      } catch (e) {
        handleError(e)
      }
      return
    }
  }
})

function handleStream (stream) {
  // do what ever you want to do with this MediaStream
  // work around to pass this as source to OBS Studio
}

function handleError (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

I can get [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) of this [`MediaStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) using [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) but not able to frame exact working approach to finally use this as source to [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/), VLC, Yuotube live or Facebook live.

What should be proper workaround to achieve this?

Comment: That sounds more like a question about obs-studio, not really about programming. You'd have better results asking at Super-User, or even directly in obs-studio's forums.

Comment: @Kaiido, its more about converting `MediaStream` to `rtmp` stream which can be put as a source to OBS, vlc, youtube live, facebook live etc.

Comment: Where is your question asking for that? Your question currently only asks how to connect it with obs-studio

Comment: @Kaiido, Thanks for pointing out. I have edited my question. Please remove your vote to close this question.

Comment: That still isn't asking for a clear programming question, so no I won't remove my vote. You basically just have made that end-user's question broader by saying you want this to work with different non-programming related products.

Comment: @Kaiido, okay then you can consider to ask others also for vote for closing this question.

Comment: It will go in a review queue, if the reviewers agree with me it'll get closed, otherwise my vote will age away. I won't do anything.